# html css image alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question regarding image alignment with CSS. For example I have created a css class as below:

```
.link {
 background: url("images/image1.gif") scroll right;
}
```

and below is the markup

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <p class="link">This is a link</p>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I check in the browser I get the image on the text. I want it after the text i mean

This is a link (this is where I want the image to appear)

Comment: p tags do not belong in the head section, but I'm guessing that's just a mistake ;) -- kibibu and spirytus have the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
.link {
  background: url("images/image1.gif") top right no-repeat;
  padding-right: 32px; /* or the width of your image */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be position right not scroll right?
You can also give the link text some padding to clear the background picture.

Comment: "position" is not valid in the [background property](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/background/).

Comment: it should be background-position or in the shorthand top right.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand right, but assuming you trying to display image right after text ends you might try something like that:

```
.link {
       background: url("images/image1.gif") scroll right;
       padding-right: 20px; /* adjust to fit nicely with your design */
}
```

hope it helps :)